# What must be modified within this function to make it slide only 4 elements every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `Slick slider` for my needs on a project and it has this function for `next` and `previous` buttons:

```
Slick.prototype.changeSlide = function(event, dontAnimate) {

    var _ = this,
        $target = $(event.target),
        indexOffset, slideOffset, unevenOffset;

    // If target is a link, prevent default action.
    $target.is('a') && event.preventDefault();

    unevenOffset = (_.slideCount % _.options.slidesToScroll !== 0);
    indexOffset = unevenOffset ? 0 : (_.slideCount - _.currentSlide) % _.options.slidesToScroll;

    switch (event.data.message) {

        case 'previous':
            slideOffset = indexOffset === 0 ? _.options.slidesToScroll : _.options.slidesToShow - indexOffset;
            if (_.slideCount > _.options.slidesToShow) {
                _.slideHandler(_.currentSlide  - slideOffset, false, dontAnimate);
            }
            break;

        case 'next':
            slideOffset = indexOffset === 0 ? _.options.slidesToScroll : indexOffset;
            if (_.slideCount > _.options.slidesToShow) {
                _.slideHandler(_.currentSlide + slideOffset, false, dontAnimate);
            }
            break;

        case 'index':
            var index = event.data.index === 0 ? 0 :
                event.data.index || $(event.target).parent().index() * _.options.slidesToScroll;

            _.slideHandler(_.checkNavigable(index), false, dontAnimate);
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }

};
```

What this does is: calculates how many elements there are in total and when I click to show me another slide it gets me from:

`1 2 3 4` to `3 4 5 6` (considering there are only 6 elements in total), but I want it to slide to `5 6` and no more (as I want it to slide 4 elements and if there are not 4 elements to show, show only as much as there are left).

What should I modify within this function to make it happen?

Comment: I've worked with slick before, can you set up a JSFiddle to play with? A different, maybe simpler strategy would be adding transparent dummy slides to the carousel until you make it a multiple of 4.

Comment: @randombumper that's actually a good idea, but if php is looping through mysql, how could I detect if the last slide isn't going to have 4 elements in it? Also I need it to be responsive so for some browser sizes it should be 3 or 2 elements and that can be defined within slicks options, how would that work with php?

Comment: I'd inject those dummy slides client-side, in Javascript. You could have a resize event handler, that: a) Removes any pre-existing dummy slides, b) Computes how many dummy slides would be needed for your current carousel and window size (if you are showing N slides per "page" and you have M slides in total, that would be `(N - M % N) % N`) and then append as many dummy slides to the end of your carousel.